# Reactjs, is setState needed here, changing value of an object in state

Tags: reactjs

**My question is, is it ok to not use `setState` in this situation or if I should, how would I go about it?**

I'm creating a sportsbetting app.

On the list of games, when a user clicks on Denver Broncos -3, a bet slip is created. This also calls 
`setState({gameSelected:[item]})` in the Parent Component.

It stores that object and adds to it using the spread operator when more bets are clicked.

### I pass down that data to betSlip.js file.

side note
Some of the data in the gameSelected object has : 
risk:'', 
win:'',

**On betSlip.js** I am looping through that data and displaying it.

Relevant code inside the loop.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Risk" onChange={(e)=>this.handleBet(e,item)}/>
<input type="text"  placeholder="Win" value={item.win}/>
```

This function is inside betSlip.js

```
 handleBet = (e,item) =>{

      let bet=e.target.value
    //function to calculate moneyline bet
      let calcBet =(bet)=>{
          let newAmount =(100/item.juice)*bet;
          return newAmount
      }

      item.win = calcBet(bet)


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be using `setState` here to update `item.win`. Otherwise, React is not aware of the mutation on `item` and does not rerender. Since `item` is a prop, you should treat it as immutable from within betSlip.js and update `item.win` through an event handler in the parent component where `item` is maintained. Your betSlip.js component could have an `onWinUpdate` handler that is called within `handleBet` as `this.props.onWinUpdate(item, calcBet(bet))`. Then, the parent component can have a function `handleWinUpdate(item, bet)` that updates the state. I would also keep things immutable in `handleWinUpdate` by doing something like this:

```
handleWinUpdate(item, bet) {
  this.setState(state => ({
    gameSelected: state.gameSelected.map(i => {
      if (i === item) {
        return { ...i, win: bet };
      } else {
        return i;
      }
    })
  }));
}
```

Notice that we are setting `gameSelected` to a new array and replacing `item` in that array with a new copy of `item`, but with a new `win` value. No objects are ever mutated.

Even though you don't have to use immutability here, I find it easier to reason about and it opens the door for performance gains later using things like [React.PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) that rely on immutability.